# не могу прикрутить калькулятор доходности, видимо проблема в js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нашел классный калькулятор https://codepen.io/StasZhuk/pen/BwaeRj, но прикрутить его не получилось.
Положил /assets/css/calc.css
и
/assets/js/calculator.js
создал html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/calc.css">
  <script src="assets/js/calculator.js"></script>

<div id="calculator">
  <span class="number-text">Количество</span>
  <span class="profit-text">Прибыль</span>
  <div class="calc-slider"></div>
  <div class="calc-bottom">
    <div class="calc-input__wrap">
       <input class="calc-input" type="text" value="10">
       <span>шт.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="calc-result__wrap">
        <div class="calc-result">1900</div>
        <span>руб.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Стиль применился.
Количество, прибыль
и окна полукруглые с 10 шт. и 1900 руб. отображаются, а сам ползунок - нет.
Подскажите, что сделал не так?
Буду очень признателен

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ! Все супер, заработало!